# How to use JQuery to remove duplicate strings from HTML

Tags: jquery

This is a dynamically created HTML list of authors with their Attirbutes:

```
<span class="authors">
    <a href="/url_one">Author One Name</a><span> - <a href="http://wsj.com">Author Attirbute String</a></span>,
    <a href="/url_one">Author Two Name</a><span> - <a href="http://wsj.com">Author Attirbute String</a></span>, and
    <a href="/url_one">Author Three Name</a><span> - <a href="http://wsj.com">Author Attirbute String</a></span>
</span>
```

How can I use JQuery to strip off each consecutive `<span> <a href="http://wsj.com">Author Attirbute String</a></span>` leaving only the last one, if they are identical and consecutive?

So, lets say I have three authors all with the same atribute of "Wall Street Journal"... I'm trying to make this:

**Author One Name - Wall Street Journal, Author Two Name - Wall Street Journal, and Author Three Name - Wall Street Journal**

be this:

**Author One Name, Author Two Name, and Author Three Name - Wall Street Journal**

It can only work if the attributes are identical and consecutive otherwise abort the function.

A couple other considerations:

1. There can be from 1 to 4 authors per HTML instance.
2. There can be a few Instances of these author lists on a page, and they all need to be handled.

Please help if ya can! I know this is complicated...

Here is a non-simplified example of what I'm doing... It is a Drupal site, and the Attributes are generated by JQuery from title tags in the code using this function which I want to modify to remove the duplicates:

```
$(function() {
  $('span.authors a').each(function() {
    $('a[href^="/authors/"]').attr('title');
    if ($(this).attr('title')) { var attrarray = $(this).attr('title').split('|');
      if (attrarray[1]) { var thespan = '<span> ~ <a href="http://' + attrarray[1] + '">' + attrarray[0] + '</a></span>'; }
      else { var thespan = '<span> ~ ' + attrarray[0] + '</span>'; }
      $(this).after(thespan); }
  });
});
```

Here is an example of the page: http://kpbj.com/authors/dee_ann_durbin

Comment: Well... I should also explain that JQuery is what generates the Attributes for the authors from Title Tags as well. I'll attach that code in an edit.

Comment: What would happen in the case of, for example, `Iain Banks` and `Iain M. Banks`; the name is different but, presumably, the link would/should point to the same place? ([They're the same author](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iain_M_Banks), incidentally, just to be clear.)

Comment: There will never be a same-author situation in each byline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Get spans.
var attributes = $('.authors').children('span');

// Save first value in variable to compare it to other elements.
var content = attributes.first().html();

// Iterate through all children and compare their values to the first one.
$.each(attributes, function(index, item){
       // Abort if not the same.
       if ($(item).html() != content) return;
   });

// All are the same. Remove all except the last one.
$.each(attributes, function(index, item) {
       if (index != attributes.length - 1) $(item).remove();
   });
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgKE6/2/)

**Update:**
Based on comments, here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgKE6/35/).

Comment: I like this. I'll see if I can incorporate this into my code. I just hope I'm not going overboard on expectations for how much a browser's JavaScript handling can do lol.

Comment: I don't think this would be a problem since there are much heavier/ more complicated scripts that browsers can handle. Good luck anyway :)

Comment: I think I'll figure out a way to just not add them instead of removing them afterward.

Comment: Actually... my code looks for the authors, then adds attributes if they exist as title tags... IS there a way to have it look back exactly one span each time and if the current one is the same remove the previous one? That way I don't have to iterate through the entire page to remove all the attributes after it added them all.

Comment: When using this on one span of authors on a page, this works well. However, I'm having great difficulty trying to make it work when there are several groups of span.author sections on a page. I really need this to work on each group independently. Can you modify it a bit to search for each group of span.authors on a page and apply your code to each one? Let me know if I'm not being clear... Thank you so much for when you've done so far.

Comment: Darn! For some reason, I cannot get this to work on my site (kpbj.com) even though when I put the source page in the fiddle and add my code it does work there. Here is the fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/VgKE6/67/ but it doesn't work on the site because the browser gives this error: "attributes.first() is not a function".  Any ideas why?

Comment: @GPiper Your site uses jquery 1.2.6 Which is very old. `first()` function was added in jquery 1.4

Comment: Any way around it other than adding a newer version of JQuery on top of the old one? (I'm kinda stuck at 1.2.6 due to Drupal 6 limitations unless I want to load two versions)

Comment: Ah! I got it... I can use ".eq(0)" instead of ".first()" and it works because ".eq()" was added in JQuery 1.1.2. :-)

Comment: Sorry I was getting back to you late. Thanks for sharing your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this style, but there you go . . . temporary solution for your problem.

```
    var allAuthors = [];
    var countAuthors = $(".authors span").length;
    $(".authors span").each(function(i){
        var authorSpan = $(this);
        if(allAuthors.indexOf($(this).html()) == -1){
            authorSpan.hide();
            allAuthors.push($(this).html());
        }else{
            if(countAuthors-i>1){
                authorSpan.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```